# Delete Column IF all column cell contain NULL value

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I need some assistance with this Python problem.

I have a table called Matrix -

```
Matrix = [[['23'],['47'],['35'],['-']],
          [['45'],['22'],['34'],['-']],
          [['11'],['43'],['22'],['-']]]
```

What I would like to do is -

Remove/Delete an entire column IF all of it's cell values contain a null value like "-".

I already have a function which deletes an entire COLUMN by its index, but before I can do that I need to find a way of knowing if every cell in that particular column contain "-" before I can delete it.

Locating "-" -

```
for i, row in enumerate(Matrix):
    for x, col in enumerate(row):
        print Matrix[i][x], i, x
```

Output -

```
['23'] 0 0

['47'] 0 1

['35'] 0 2

['-'] 0 3

['45'] 1 0

['22'] 1 1

['34'] 1 2

['-'] 1 3

['11'] 2 0

['43'] 2 1

['22'] 2 2

['-'] 2 3
```

from this I can see that "-" does exist in each cell within column 3.

my attempt -

```
    for i, row in enumerate(Matrix):
        for x, col in enumerate(row):
            if "-" in col:
                print "Column to Delete is", x
```

p.s. I know I would have to do this in reverse, but I'm more interested in the logic of this.

Comment: The code you give isn't an attempted solution - it's just printing out the data. You need to try and do what you want, and then if you have a problem, come back and ask about that specific issue.

Comment: But thats where Im stuck, I did my research and didnt found anything. I just need the logic to solve it myself really.

Comment: If you really can't conceive even the most naive approach to solving this, I suggest you read some basic programming tutorials to grasp the basics before continuing.

Comment: ok I'll add my ideas.

Comment: Ive added my idea, so now i can locate where the "-" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as now we have seen your attempt, I would suggest you to grasp some concepts of Python and get an understanding of Python's libraries and [builtins](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), esp, in this case, you need to understand [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [all](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all). You also need to understand about iterable and List Comprehension.

Zip is a wonderful function, and comes handy with the splat operator `*` when transposing Matrix. In this case, as you can access the rows through index but not the columns (unlike in Numpy), your first attempt should be to transpose the data.

```
>>> Matrix = [[['23'],['47'],['35'],['-']],
          [['45'],['22'],['34'],['-']],
          [['11'],['43'],['22'],['-']]]
>>> zip(*Matrix)
[(['23'], ['45'], ['11']), (['47'], ['22'], ['43']), (['35'], ['34'], ['22']), (['-'], ['-'], ['-'])]
```

Once you have all the Column data in a single row, your next attempt should be to find out, which row contains all ['-']. You can use the builtin [all](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) which returns true if all the elements are true.

You also need to know, how to navigate through the rows in the transpose Matrix. List Comprehension and or generator expression comes handy

```
[row for row in zip(*Matrix) if all(e != ['-'] for e in row)]
```

which is an equivalent concise notation for the following loop

```
_Matrix = []
for row in  zip(*Matrix):
    #all(e != ['-'] for e in row)
    _cond = True
    for e in row:
        if e != ['-']:
               _cond = False
               break
    if not _cond:
        _Matrix.append(e)
```

Now, once you remove the target row, you need to transpose back the data to get the original form, sans the column with all the ['-'] removed

```
zip(*(row for row in zip(*Matrix) if all(e != ['-'] for e in row)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, ive taken you comments onboard and will do my research. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How would you do it if you needed to do it yourself? In english

Read a column,
if the column contains only "-" delete it

Read a column :
Loop on Matrix[0-N][column number]
set a variable to false if you encouter something else than "-"

Delete a column : 
Loop on Matrix[0-n][column number] and remove each element

you need to know the following :

```
How to know the number of lines : len(Matrix)
how to know the number of column : len(Matrix[0])
How to remove a element : del matrix[rowNumber][columnNumber]
```

which gives you the following (a little easier to understand than the other awnser for a newbie) :

```
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

def getMatrixNumberOfRows(Matrix):
    return len(Matrix)

def getMatrixNumberOfColumns(Matrix):
    return len(Matrix[0])

def mustColumnBeDeleted(Matrix, columnNumber):
    mustBeDeleted = True
    for rowNumber in range(0, getMatrixNumberOfRows(Matrix)):
        if Matrix[rowNumber][columnNumber] != ['-']:
            mustBeDeleted = False
    return mustBeDeleted

def deleteColumn(Matrix, columnNumber):
    for rowNumber in range(0, getMatrixNumberOfRows(Matrix)):
        del Matrix[rowNumber][columnNumber]

def printMatrix(Matrix):
    for row in Matrix:
        print row

#program

Matrix = [[['23'],['47'],['35'],['-']],
          [['45'],['22'],['34'],['-']],
          [['11'],['43'],['22'],['-']]]

for columnNumber in range(0, getMatrixNumberOfColumns(Matrix)):
    if mustColumnBeDeleted(Matrix, columnNumber) == True:
        deleteColumn(Matrix, columnNumber)

printMatrix(Matrix)
```

output :

```
[['23'], ['47'], ['35']]
[['45'], ['22'], ['34']]
[['11'], ['43'], ['22']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, it really helped me understand your script. I wish I could accept both answers!